# Is there any less code way to make a leaf (eye) shape in CSS?

Tags: code-golf, tips, css

I'm trying to solve a [CSS challenge](https://cssbattle.dev/play/141). It contains a rotated leaf shape (looks like an eye). Score for the challenge depends on amount of characters of the code. Here's my way to make a leaf shape:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 99% 0;
  rotate: 45deg;
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Here's my whole solution for the challenge if you need a bigger picture:

```css
* {
  background:#E3516E;
}
p {
  height:99px;
  width:99px;
  background:#d9d9d9;
  border-radius:0 0 81q;
  margin:-31px;
}
[i] {
  rotate:45deg;
  margin:55px 142px;
  border-radius:99%0;
}
p+p {
  margin:-30px 316px;
  scale:-1;
}
```

```html
<p><p i><p>
```

Minified version of the above:

```
<p><p i><p><style>*{background:#E3516E}p{height:99;width:99;background:#d9d9d9;border-radius:0 0 81q;margin:-31}[i]{margin:55 142;rotate:45deg;border-radius:99%0}p+p{margin:-30 316;scale:-1
```

Is there any way with less code for the eye shape? Maybe with clip-path, borders or something like that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

## 77 bytes

```html
<p style=width:5em;height:5em;border-radius:99%0;rotate:45deg;background:#080
```

```html
<p style=width:5em;height:5em;border-radius:99%0;rotate:45deg;background:#080
```

- Use a `p` tag instead of a `div`
- Omit the closing `>`
- Remove all white space within the CSS
- Use an inline `style` attribute
- Use `em` instead of `px` for units of measurement
- Use 3 digit hex colours instead of named colours
- Omit the last `;`

You can save another byte using `4rad` in place of `45deg`, but the angle won't be *exactly* right:

```html
<p style=width:5em;height:5em;border-radius:99%0;rotate:4rad;background:#080
```

Comment: I've already done all of those as you could see in my minified version. Unfortunately I cannot use 3 digit hex color cause the leaf color is #d9d9d9. Also I guess I shouldn't use style here cause I share styles between 3 p tags